# net/core/filter.c and linux/bpf/verifier.c

Tags: c, kernel, bpf, ebpf

If I understood well initially the cBPF verifier and interpreter were both within `net/core/fiter.c` for example `sk_run_filter` here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.2/source/net/core/filter.c#L112 just convert the cBPF instructions applying them on the emulated registers and directly on the sk_buff. 
While `sk_chk_filter` check if the instructions are all legal.

Currently I've seen that there is still a `bpf_check_classic` function in filter.c which substitutes the old `sk_chk_filter`. After the check there is an attempt to JIT the program, if is not possible the next step is to convert the cBPF in eBPF.

**QUESTIONS:**

1) where is actually the call to run the jitted/converted cbpf filter in the last `net/core/filter.c`?

2) Which is the  sequence of function calls which bring a cBPF program to be executed as an eBPF program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, cBPF program are only used for seccomp-bpf and as socket filters.

- For seccomp-bpf, the actual call is in [`kernel/seccomp.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/kernel/seccomp.c#L272), after the program has been converted to eBPF.
- For socket filters, the actual call is in [`net/core/filter.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/net/core/filter.c#L119), as you guessed. `sk_filter_trim_cap()` then gets [called in a number of places](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc7/ident/sk_filter_trim_cap) in the kernel, for all types of sockets.